# Javascript replace value inside span tag that has attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a way to find a span tag inside an HTML and replace the value between the span tag, by using regex. But it should only replace if the span tag contains a specific attribute
For example

`<span a="hello">a</span><span>b</span>` needs to become `<span a="hello">c</span><span>b</span>`

Is this possible to do in regex? Why I need to do this with regex is because this code runs on the server side and don't have access to allot of fancy Javascript functions.

Comment: DOM parsers are available in other languages than just client-side JavaScript ...

Comment: …including server-side JavaScript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: somethig like ^<span.+yourAttr=.+>(.*)<\/span>$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a regex solution that worked for me. Know that this is not the best solution but it's the easiest solution on my environment (Adobe Campaign).

```
html.replace(/(<span[\s\S]*a="hello"[\s\S]*?>)([\s\S]*?)(<\/span>)/g, "$1" + "c" + "$3")
```